# How can I access the "this" in my controller when using "the controller as" syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name1 = 'Parent';
  this.name1 = 'Parent';
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name1 = 'Child';
  this.name1 = 'Child';
  this.option = {};
  this.option.abc = 25;

  foo = function(){
    alert(this.option)
  };

  foo();
});
```

When I try to access the "this" before the function it is available. When I try to access the this inside of the function then it's undefined. Can someone tell me is there an "AngularJS" way to resolve this?

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest 1.2.16

Comment: you can set the context of the foo function `foo.call(this);`. Usually the context in functions will be `window` or `null` if you are using strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the reference of this at the start of the function and use that. The context of `this` i believe in your function is the global window. It all depends upon how the function is invoked and where is it defined.

```
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope) {
  var self=this;
  $scope.name1 = 'Child';
  this.name1 = 'Child';
  this.option = {};
  this.option.abc = 25;

  foo = function(){
    alert(self.option)
  };

  foo();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It works good. Do you think it would be a good idea for me to all use self when setting variables outside the function. For example self.name1 = 'Child' etc. ?

Comment: You can assign variable using `this`. The problem is with the function invocation. Depending on how the function is invoked the context of `this` changes. If you had defined function `this.foo=function()` and then called `this.foo()`, things would work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `Controller As` Syntax then declarations like:

```
$scope.name1 = 'Child';
this.name1 = 'Child';
```

are redundant. When you specify the 'As' angular will copy over all properties defined on this, to a $scope variable.

as for why `this` doesn't work in your function. The this keyword refers to the executing context of the function. As you have declared it there is no context. To get `this` to be what you expect it you can do:

```
this.foo = function(){...this is this...}
```

or if you don't wish to expose it on the scope. You can use the module revealing pattern.

```
var self = this;
function foo(){...self is 'this'...};
```