# Without using the module revealing pattern is there a way I can access "this" inside an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have the following code. Is the only way that I can get access to the `this` inside of the function by using the `self` variable or is there another way that I can access the `this` inside the function ?

```
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, _o) {

  var self=this;
  this.option = {};
  this.option.abc = 25;

  $q.all([_o.getUserProfiles(),
          _u.getConfigs()
        ])
        .then(function (results) {
            ???.option.userProfiles = results[0].userProfiles;
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bind. May be this will be more comfortably for you.

```
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, _o) {

  this.option = {};
  this.option.abc = 25;

  $q.all([_o.getUserProfiles(),
          _u.getConfigs()
        ])
        .then(function (results) {
            this.option.userProfiles = results[0].userProfiles;
        }.bind(this));
```

More about bind you can read here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: I opened up a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577814/how-can-i-access-the-this-in-my-controller-when-using-the-controller-as-synt  Could I also use .bind for the foo function there?

Comment: This is one of the reasons I use coffeescript :) Try this: http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow